# Two dissection problems for rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, tiling, rectangles, dissection

Let us consider two integer rectangles (that is, with sides of integer length) $S$ and $T$ of the same area. Then, obviously, $S$ can be dissected into several integer rectangles $A_1$, ..., $A_n$ (we will call such a dissection a *tiling*, and the rectangles constituting it *tiles*) which can be rearranged to form $T$ (e.g., dissect $S$ into unit squares).

**Question #1.** *Is there any non-constant lower bound (expressed as some function of dimensions of rectangles $S$ and $T$) for the size of such a tiling?*

(**Size of the tiling** is its cardinality, the number of the tiles it consists of)

This sounds rather vague. Also there is an issue of the dimensions of $S$ and $T$ having common divisors. Let me formulate a very specific question (perhaps even somewhat too specific but...).

**Question #1.1.** *Let $p < q < r < s$ be four different prime numbers, $S$ --- rectangle with dimensions $pq \times rs$, T --- rectangle with dimensions $pr \times qs$. Does there exist a function $f(p,q,r,s)$ which
a) serves as a lower bound for the above-mentioned tiling size;
b) tends to infinity if all four arguments tend to infinity?*

A possible answer: $f(p,q,r,s) = h(p)$, where $h:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ tends to infinity as its argument tends to infinity (like $\log p$, for example).

Another (similar but diferent) interesting question of a similar nature (also quite specific):

**Question #2.** *Given a natural number $n$, let $S$ be the rectangle with dimensions $n \times (n+1)$, and $T$ the rectangle with dimensions $(n+1) \times n$. Is there a non-constant lower bound (as a function of $n$) for the size of a tiling of $S$ such that its tiles can be moved **without rotating them** to form $T$?*

Perhaps we should concentrate first on the following simplified version of Question 2.

**Question #2.1.** *If $n = 1000000$, then is it possible to dissect an $n \times (n+1)$ rectangle into less than $20$ integer rectangles which can be moved (without rotation) to form an $(n+1)\times n$ rectangle?*

**Note.** Don't try to dissect into square tiles. It can be proved (although the only elementary proof I know is neither very short nor very elementary) that $(n+1) \times n$ rectangle **cannot** be dissected into less than $\log_2(n)$ square tiles.

Comment: What is the size of a tiling here? Is it the area of the largest tile? The number of tiles used?

Comment: Size of tiling is simply the number of its tiles. Sorry, if that was not clear. I will update the text.

Comment: For 1 observe that $1 \times 4$ can be cut into two pieces that can make $2 \times 2$.  We can scale both by any factor, so we can do this with arbitrarily large area.  I think the question as written is missing some restrictions that you have in mind.  What is the lower bound based on?  Please clarify.  We ask that each post have a single question.  This clearly does not.

Comment: I agree that Q.1 is too general; that's why I have Q.1.1 as well as Q.2.1. I have made a small edit as well.

Comment: As to the issue of having two questions in the same post - I think it makes sense as they are most likely very much related to each other. If that is completely inappropriate, I can, of course, split this post into two, not a problem - however I think it would be logical to keep them together.

Comment: For Q1, I don't see how you can dissect a $1\times n^2$ into an $n\times n$ using fewer than $n$ pieces. For 1.1, I think a similar argument would apply if $p,q$ are small while $r,s$ are large.

Comment: @GerryMyerson . Yes, to your first point, for that specific example; but the dimensions of $S$ and $T$ could be large and co-prime --- Q.1. is more of a general, investigation-style problem. To the second - suppose that some monotonically increasing and unbound function of $p$ (the smallest prime) such as $\log n$ or $\sqrt n$ is proven to be the desired lower bound. That would "solve" the Q.1.1